# Showing that a topology is coarser than another using neighborhood basis

Tags: general-topology

I have the following statement that I need to prove:
Let $ \tau_{1} $and $ \tau_{2}$ be two topologies on the set $X$ and for every $x\in X$ let $\mathcal B^{1}(x)$ and $\mathcal B^2(x)$ be bases of a Neighborhood-System of x in respectively $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau{2}$.

Prove that:

$\tau_{1}$ is coarser(weaker) than $\tau{2}$ $\iff \forall x \in X, \space\forall B^1\in \mathcal B^{1}(x) \exists B^2\in\mathcal B^2(x):B^2 \subseteq B^1 $

So I am completely stuck. I understand that for a topology to be coarser it needs to fufill the condition that $\tau_{1} \subseteq \tau_{2}$, and I tried to start with an element of $\tau_{1}$ and tried to find a connection with the right hand side but without success. I know also that these neighborhood bases need to fufill 3 conditions and I know the conditions but I am not certain at all at how that might help me out eventually in this case.

I would be very thankful for any sort of help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  The given condition means anything open in $\tau_1$ is open in $\tau_2$.  That is, let $U\in\tau_1$.  Then let $x\in U$. Then there is $B_1\in\tau_1$ such that $x\in B_1\subset U$.  By the given condition there is $B_2\in\tau_2$ such that $x\in B_2\subset B_1\subset U$.  Thus $U\in\tau_2$.

Comment: could you please expand a little bit more on that and how that can further help me

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: Thank you, what about the $ \rightarrow $ direction of the proof

Comment: It is also a straightforward working through of the definitions.

Comment: I don't really think it is that straightforward especially in an introduction course with these concepts. If I may ask you are $B^1$ or $mathcal B^1(x)$ subsets of $tau_{1}$ and could you please help me how that can further help me

Comment: Yes, my $B_1\in\tau_1$.  I don't want to take away the fun of doing the entire exercise from you.  But on the other direction, remember the definition of open set.